# Mongoengine ValidationError You can only reference documents once they have been saved to the database

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

***Summary***: (Python+Flask+MongoDB) Defined two models - `User` and `Post`. `Post` references `User`. Trying to create a `Post` by referencing a saved `User` but getting `You can only reference documents once they have been saved to the database` error.

***Detail***
Hello! I'm following a python (*installed v3.7*), flask (*installed v1.1.2*), MongoDB (*installed mongoengine v0.23.0*) tutorial to write a simple blogging app.
I have a `User` model and a `Post` model. A `User` may register, login and write Posts. I am able to create and save Users. However, when I try to create a `Post` by referencing a (previously created & saved) `User`, I get a *Mongoengine ValidationError* `You can only reference documents once they have been saved to the database`

The `User` object referenced in the `Post` object is present in the DB - confirmed that via the Mongo shell.

Any pointers/help/inputs would be much appreciated. I am new to MongoDB.

***Code***

```
# models.py 
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine 

db = MongoEngine()

class User(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField()
    username = db.StringField(required = True)
    email = db.EmailField(required = True)

class Post(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField()
    created_by = db.ReferenceField(User)
    title = db.StringField(required = True)
    body = db.StringField(required = True)

# blog.py 
""" Module that creates blog posts 
from app.models import User, Post

def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        
        user = User.objects.get(_id=g.user['_id']) 
        # check user fetched by printing object id 
        # user[_id] matches the User ObjectID obtained via the mongo shell
        print('user id = ' + str(user['_id'])) 

        post = Post(title=title, body=body)
        post.created_by = user
        post.save() # --> this line generates the error 
        return redirect(url_for('blog.index')) 

    return render_template('blog/create.html')
```

***Error***
File "/Users/<my_username>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 433, in validate
raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors)
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Post:None) (You can only reference documents once they have been saved to the database: ['created_by'])

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084136/save-reference-field-mongoengine) Stackoverflow question, I was able to make this work by saving the `User` and then passing the `DBRef` of the User into the `Post`.

```
user = User.objects.get(_id=g.user['_id'])
user.save()
post = Post(title=title, body=body) 
post.created_by = user.to_dbref()
post.save()
```